# Connecting Presto and Apache SuperSet

Tags: database, presto, apache-superset, trino

I have presto and apache superset hosted at GCP Cloud.
 Presto server hosted at `http://14.22.122.12:8088/ui/`

But when i try to connect Presto to Superset it's giving me this error

```
Could not load database driver: presto
```

Already installed the presto driver using `pip install pyhive`.

Not sure what's wrong here ? My SQLAlchemyURL  `presto://14.22.122.12:8088/catalog_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error usually appears when the driver isn't available (so the connection string format isn't recognized).

I would confirm that the pip install happened correctly. If you're running everything within docker, make sure you rebuilt properly. You can enter the docker cli, fire up a Python shell, and try to import the presto driver (you can also try `pip freeze` in the docker cli).

Comment: they probably don't need to mention ":8088" in the uri because it already mentions "presto"